# Watts and relation with A/V

Tags: led, watts

I have a doubt about some numbers I'm getting in LiveWire... Can anybody explain origin of these values?

I believed that watts come from Amperes x Volts, but these ciphers are driving me crazy...

I get that

P = I * V

V = P / I (fixed)

V = 5.46 / 6.63

V = 0,8235 --- what is this number? It isn't V drop from de led, and is not V from batteries... What represents this number?

Thanks in advance!

edit: I changed the image, to be coherent with values and not to-fry the led! The example is mine, I knew that It was an impossible situation... Just wondering about Watts value, what's the calculation that throws 5,49 mW?

The formula was mistaken, thank you Brian Drummond!

**Edit 2:**

It's possible that the value reflects led's resistance? I mean:

P = IV

V=P/I

V = 5.46mW / 6.63mA

V = 0,82V (V "efficiently" consumed by led)

1.5V - 0.82V = 0.676V (V "wasted" by led)

calculating resistance:

V = RI

R = V/I

R = 0.676V / 6.63 mA

R = 676mV / 6.63 mA

R = 101,96 Ohm

I't possible that nearly 102 ohm are the "resistance" coming from led? Or It's implicit in V drop from led and I'm calculating it twice?

[image]

Comment: Units are in mA and mW, but result is same using A and W.

Comment: Your circuit is broken. Where is the current-limiting resistor?

Comment: This is a great illustration of the difference between a simulated circuit and a real circuit. In real life you would have totally fried the LED. Do these numbers make any sense? No. Yet there is an underlying assumption that they must be correct.

Comment: There is also a trivial mistake in the second formula. Correct for that and it's an infra-red LED.

Comment: It's possible that the value reflects led's resistance?

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example of a badly constructed example, and it's no wonder you are having a hard time.

The big problem is that you are showing a 9 volt battery which appears to be driving an LED at 80 mA. Well, to be fair, a nearly dead 9 volt battery will do this (for a while), but that's not very likely.

As you can see from [this link](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/522.pdf), a fresh 9 volt battery will put out 300 mA for about an hour while keeping the voltage above 5 or 6 volts.

Apparently, the originator of your circuit was trying to illustrate the power/voltage/current relationship, and really intended to show "some unknown voltage source" in the drawing, and carelessly used a battery as his symbol.

If you correct your second equation (as Brian Drummond pointed out) you'll find the numbers are about right for an IR LED.

Comment: Thanks, I know it's an impossible situation... Just wondering what calculation throws 5,46 mW?

Comment: @user675319 - The only way the calculation can work is if the voltage equals .824 volts. Then power equals volts times current.